# How to get a list of tags and create new tags with python and dulwich in git?

Tags: python, git, dulwich

I am having problems to retrieve the following information of a git repo using python:

1. I would like to get a list of all tags of this repository.
2. I would like to checkout another branch and also create a new branch for staging.
3. I would like to tag a commit with an annotated tag.

I have looked into the dulwich's documentation and the way it works seems very bare-bones. Are there also alternatives which are easier to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way to get all tags using Dulwich is:

```
from dulwich.repo import Repo
r = Repo("/path/to/repo")
tags = r.refs.as_dict("refs/tags")
```

*tags* is now a dictionary mapping tags to commit SHA1s.

Checking out another branch:

```
r.refs.set_symbolic_ref("HEAD", "refs/heads/foo")
r.reset_index()
```

Creating a branch:

```
r.refs["refs/heads/foo"] = head_sha1_of_new_branch
```

Comment: hi @jelmer, thanks for the project :)

Any chance of an example of how to a.add tag b.push tags to remote?

Comment: Great it's useful! Please ask a new question about that, I think that's a different topic.

Comment: Sure, done @jelmer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60139728/add-tag-push-tags-to-remote-in-python-dulwich

Answer (score 2):

Now you can also get an [alphabetically](https://github.com/jelmer/dulwich/blob/2a3ce7b7804c0e0e04033e604902ced99cedf8e7/dulwich/porcelain.py#L437-L446) sorted list of tag labels.

```
from dulwich.repo import Repo
from dulwich.porcelain import tag_list

repo = Repo('.')
tag_labels = tag_list(repo)
```

Comment: Great! Seems like no way to get the SHA1 part from porcelain though

Answer (score 1):

Call git via `subprocess`. From one of my own programs:

```
def gitcmd(cmds, output=False):
    """Run the specified git command.

    Arguments:
    cmds   -- command string or list of strings of command and arguments
    output -- wether the output should be captured and returned, or
              just the return value
    """
    if isinstance(cmds, str):
        if ' ' in cmds:
            raise ValueError('No spaces in single command allowed.')
        cmds = [cmds] # make it into a list.
    # at this point we'll assume cmds was a list.
    cmds = ['git'] + cmds # prepend with git
    if output: # should the output be captured?
        rv = subprocess.check_output(cmds, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).decode()
    else:
        with open(os.devnull, 'w') as bb:
            rv = subprocess.call(cmds, stdout=bb, stderr=bb)
    return rv
```

Some examples:

```
rv = gitcmd(['gc', '--auto', '--quiet',])
outp = gitcmd('status', True)
```