# add tag / push tags to remote in Python Dulwich

Tags: python, git, dulwich

I like the [Dulwich](https://www.dulwich.io/) project as it provides pure Python interface to interacting with git.

It looks pretty low-level though... While I couldn't find reference on how to perform simple tasks.

My need's are pretty simple, provide the same as below git CLI commands:

1. `git push --tags --force`
2. `git tag --force`
3. `git show-ref --tags` (provides mapping between tag and the commit it points on)

Update:
looks like item #3 is answered here:
[How to get a list of tags and create new tags with python and dulwich in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909962/how-to-get-a-list-of-tags-and-create-new-tags-with-python-and-dulwich-in-git/16639853?noredirect=1#comment106307178_16639853) (by Jelmer the creator of Dulwich)

Answer (score 1):

The dulwich.porcelain (https://www.dulwich.io/docs/api/dulwich.porcelain.html#module-dulwich.porcelain) module is somewhat more high level, and should do what you need.

Specifically, the push and tag_create functions. Note that there is currently no force argument since all tag editing is currently done without safety checking.